# How to denote sum of tiled matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, tensors

I have two matrices $\mathbf{A}, \mathbf{B} \in \mathbb{R}^{L \times M}$, which I tile and add to get $\mathbf{C} \in \mathbb{R}^{L \times L \times M}$ with $c_{ijk} = a_{ik} + b_{jk}$. How can I write this as a good-looking matrix / vector operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I can write

$$
\mathbf{C} = [\,\mathbf{C}_i\,] \qquad \text{with} \qquad \mathbf{C}_i = \mathbf{1}_L \otimes \mathbf{a}_i + \mathbf{B}
$$

where $\mathbf{a}_i$ is the $i$-th the row of $\mathbf{A}$, which sufficiently illustrates what this operation does.